# Django UpdateView not saving whether new user or existing user using ModelForm

Tags: python, django, modelform

I am writing an UpdateView `UpdateAccountView` for the `User` model, updating through a ModelForm `MyUserCreationForm` which is already the ModelForm used for creating new users. The problem is that whenever I click Submit to save the changes in the template, it rerenders the template.

For instance, if I didn't change any fields, it gives me error of "Username is already taken" which I will show you in the `MyUserCreationForm` to check for unique usernames, or just rerenders the template for new entries on the fields, without actually saving any changes to the model.

Here is my `MyUserCreationForm`

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User #extended from auth.models.User
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "username", "email", "gender", "profile_photo")

    # adding bootstrap styling to the ModelForm fields
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control input-lg',
                'placeholder': field.replace("_", " ").title(),
                'tabindex': list(self.fields).index(field) + 1})
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.pop('autofocus', None)

            if field == 'username' or field == 'email':
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                    'placeholder': field.replace("_", " ").title() + ' *',
                })


    def clean_username(self):

        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if not re.search(r'^[\w.-]+$', username):
             raise forms.ValidationError('Username can only contain alphanumeric characters, dots, hyphens ,and underscores')
        try:
             User.objects.get(username=username)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
             return username
        raise forms.ValidationError('Username is already taken.')
```

and here is the view class `UpdateAccountView`

```
class UpdateAccountView(UpdateView):
    form_class = MyUserCreationForm
    model = User
    template_name = 'auth/account-edit.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```

**However,** if I directly update the Model by using model and fields in the `UpdateView`, it works fine. But I need to do it through the `ModelForm` to have control over the styles when rendering.

So I know that the problem lies within `ModelForm` but I cannot find it, even after searching a lot.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to use a creation form for updating the object. In particular, the `UserCreation` form has code which sets the password. which may cause you problems. It might be better to factor out the code that styles the template into a separate mixin.

Comment: I would rather go for this option if I knew it. I mean it would be better for me to separate the style from the ModelForm `init` widget
Could you please refer me how to style the modelform in a mixin?

Comment: I can't -- I don't know what "some other code" is

Comment: Sorry, I updated this part to show the styling I did to the widget attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try moving the code that styles the fields in to a separate mixin:

```
class UserStyleMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserStyleMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Style the fields here
```

Then you can make your `MyUserCreationForm` use the mixin, and create a new form for the update view.

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserStyleMixin, UserCreationForm):
    ...

class UserUpdateForm(UserStyleMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    ...
```

Note that if the update view allows the user to change the username, then you should still check that the username is allowed and unique. If you have `unique=True` for the username in your model, Django should take care of this for you. It would be a good idea to move the username regex to the model as well.

Comment: Very good! Yea I created a new ModelForm for the updateview and now it's working well. I also did the mixin.

BTW, my `User` model inherits from django `AbstractUser` which has cool features set up already to check for uniqueness and correctness. I removed the whole `clean_username` function and I let django takes care of it.

Thank you for the answer.